# call 64-bit exe and 32-bit exe as a single file

Tags: windows, batch-file, 32bit-64bit

How can I call a 64-bit exe from a 32-bit exe in windows 7?
My requirement is I have created a batch file and have converted into exe using iexpress.
This exe works fine when I converted this exe from a 32-bit pc for a 32-bit pc.
And This exe works fine when I converted this exe from a 64-bit pc for a 64-bit pc.

When I tried to run 64bit from 31bit pc it show error `Not valid`

But I need to include this both for a single installation and call.

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excuse me, I think there is a misunderstanding here.

I understand that you have *both* .exe versions of a same program, one for 32-bit and one for 64-bit. However, you want NOT to *execute both versions* in every computer, but just the *appropriate version* for the underlaying OS, isn't it?

This way, you must *include* both .exe files in the installation files, but copy *just one* in the computer, so you just need to identify the version of the installing computer:

```
if exist "%SYSTEMDRIVE%\Program Files (x86)" (
   rem The OS is 64 bit
   copy D:\program_v64.exe C:\program.exe
) else (
   rem The OS is 32 bit
   copy D:\program_v32.exe C:\program.exe
)
```